# invalid CFArrayRef problem with Singleton object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, singleton, nsarray

I've built a singleton object to manage some data in my app

```
@interface MyCommon : NSObject {

    NSArray *quizz;
    int iCurrentQuestion;

};

+ (MyCommon *)singleton;

@property (retain) NSArray *quizz;
@property (assign) int iCurrentQuestion;

@end

MyCommon.m

#import "MyCommon.h"


// MyCommon.m:
@implementation MyCommon

static MyCommon * MyCommon_Singleton = nil;


@synthesize iCurrentQuestion;

+ (MyCommon *)singleton
{
    if (nil == MyCommon_Singleton)
    {
        MyCommon_Singleton = [[MyCommon alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"allocating MyCommon_Singleton at %@",MyCommon_Singleton);
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"accessing singleton : %@", MyCommon_Singleton);
    }

    return MyCommon_Singleton;
}


- (NSArray*) getQuizz{

    return quizz;
}

- (void) setQuizz:(NSArray *)array {

    quizz = [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];

    NSLog(@"setQuizz : %@",quizz);    
}
```

There is no problem for writing the quizz object (setQuizz), however when I try to access it for reading, I get a crash : the quizz looks invalid and Xcode notify me an invalid CFArrayRef

I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provide a custom setter for `quizz` but it doesn't comply with how the property is declared.

You're not retaining `quizz` when you're setting a new value. It's likely to be released just after, leading to a crash when you access it.

You should write

```
- (void)setQuizz:(NSArray *)array {
    if (quizz != array) {
        NSArray *tmp = quizz;
        quizz = [array retain]; // retain the new value
        [tmp release]; // release the old one
    }
    NSLog(@"setQuizz : %@",quizz);
}
```

Comment: did you forgot something in the code above? i get setQuizz (null) on the log

Comment: @N-AccessDev sorry for the typo. I had written `tmp = [array retain]` instead of `quizz = [array retain]`

Answer (score 0):

this is way more code than it needs to be. First if you are going to be providing your own method you should declare so in the @property declaration which you didn't. Also  your not properly retaining your variables. Additionally you should be using dispatch_once() for a thread safe & fast way to guarantee the singleton is only created once.

```
@interface MyCommon : NSObject {}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *quiz;
@property (assign) int iCurrentQuestion;

+ (MyCommon *)singleton;

@end

@implementation MyCommon

@synthesize quiz;
@synthesize iCurrentQuestion;

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        quiz = [[NSMutableArray alloc init];
        iCurrentQuestion = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (MyCommon *)singleton {
    static MyCommon *singleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t pred;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        singleton = [[MyCommon alloc] init];
    });
    return singleton;
}

@end
```

then you just do

```
[MyCommon singleton].quiz = //some array
```